# Submit data to database from two different page

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I kinda new in this Codeigniter coding in general actually and im trying to submit a value from 2 different page and put it in 1 table, so far i can only submit a value from 1 page, is it possible submit 2 value to 1 table?

column in my table :

`po_no, tgl_po, rev_po, vendor_po, pic_po, tofp_po, kurs_po, location_po, catatan_po`

my model to add value to my database

```
public function addPurchaseOrder()
{
    $data = [
        "vendor_po" => $this->input->post('vendor',true),
        "tgl_po"=>$this->input->post('tanggal',true),
        "po_no" =>$this->input->post('po',true),
        "rev_po"=>$this->input->post('rev',true),
        "ref_po"=>$this->input->post('ref',true),
        "pic_po"=>$this->input->post('pic',true),
        "location_po"=>$this->input->post('location',true),
        "tofp_po"=>$this->input->post('top',true),
        "kurs_po"=>$this->input->post('kurs',true),
        "catatan_po"=>$this->input->post('catatan',true)
    ];
    $this->db->insert('purchase_order',$data);
}
```

my form structure basically

- Page 1: insert catatan_po

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="catatan" class="control-label">Notes : </label>
      <div class="row mt-4">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
           <textarea name="catatan" id="catatan" cols="151" rows="15"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <a href="<?php base_url(); ?>tampil" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="buton">Submit</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

- Page 2 :

this page basically fill all the table column except catatan_po the different one is the button

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:50px;" id="buton">Save</button>
   <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="buton" href="<?php base_url(); ?>otorisasi">Back</a>
</div>
```

am I doing it right?

Comment: then dont use two different page, just use two div and hide show it and submit all data togather.

Comment: well even if i only use 1 page there's nothing wrong with learning something new right?